# Getting permission denied in fluent-bit docker container

Tags: docker, fluent-bit

I have created docker container with fluent-bit but when I try to execute the docker entrypoint.sh I'm getting permission denied. below i attached the docker file

```
FROM fluent/fluent-bit:1.4-debug

USER root


ADD ./docker-fluentbit-entrypoint.sh /fluent-bit

CMD ["chmod", "+x", "/fluent-bit/docker-fluentbit-entrypoint.sh"]

ADD fluent-bit.conf /fluent-bit/etc/

WORKDIR /fluent-bit

ENTRYPOINT ["/fluent-bit/docker-fluentbit-entrypoint.sh"]
```

getting below error message

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/fluent-bit/docker-fluentbit-entrypoint.sh\": permission denied": unknown.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CMD command by RUN command.

```
RUN chmod +x /fluent-bit/docker-fluentbit-entrypoint.sh
```

CMD executes when you launch the built image while RUN is an image build step.

Comment: if I give run command then image is not created  getting this exception "OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/bin/sh\\\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory\"

Comment: Because you are not having bash in your container. Add it like this RUN apk update &&  apk add bash

Comment: fluentbit is not alpine linux image so will it support if I give this command

Comment: it is distroless base image  so how could I install bash here